# Local webserver not accessible from local network using external IP / domain

Tags: webserver

I have a VM running a simple webhost.

But whenever I try to connect to it using my external IP (148.123.29.35)
or domain (test.mydomain.com (A-record to 148.123.29.35)),
my browser just tries to connect, then ends with "This webpage is unavailable".

This only happens from my local network, I have tested over VPN to my work place and it works fine from there, and a friend also tested for me.

I am using Asus RT-AC66U router with portforwarding port 80 to 192.168.1.200

Following is the result of a tracert request in cmd:

---

C:\Users\Username>tracert test.mydomain.com

Tracing route to test.mydomain.com [148.123.29.35]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

- 1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  x.x.x.x.customer.cdi.cc [148.123.29.35]

Trace complete.

---

Following is the result of a tracert request in cmd to google.com

---

C:\Users\Username>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [148.123.29.35]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

- 1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1]
- 2 - 8                        << Hidden >>
- 9     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  148.123.29.35

Trace complete.

---

I also want to point out that I am currently running a Space Engineers server which is working perfectly,
both from internal and external computers (obviously port-forwarded..)

### NOTE:

- My actual domain has been replaced by test.mydomain.com
- My actual external IP has been replaced by 148.123.29.35 (google.com)
- My actual username has been replaced by Username
- My actual cdi. address has been replaced by cdi.cc
- Other IPs have been replaced by x.x.x.x

Comment: Also: [Connecting to own IP not working](http://superuser.com/questions/371823/connecting-to-own-ip-not-working/371838#371838), [Problem Accessing my public IP on my computer](http://superuser.com/questions/340287/problem-accessing-my-public-ip-on-my-computer), [Port Forwarding not working in DSL Router](http://superuser.com/questions/454458/port-forwarding-not-working-in-dsl-router), etc, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your router may not have NAT Loopback enabled.
Some routers have it disabled by default.
Enabling it will depend on your router,
some may have an option in the Admin Page,
others, may require you to telnet the router and execute a command.

Comment: More info available at http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers

Comment: In the end I flashed the router with TomatoUSB by Shibby, which works perfectly. I guess it's the NAT Loopback which I did not find anything about on my router, it seems to be lacking this functionality...